# exception catching for int divided by 0

Tags: c++, exception

Recently i was trying a simple exception program in C++ which goes like this:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=5, y=0;
    try
    {
       int z=x/y;
       cout<<"z="<<z;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
       cout<<"exception caught: "<<e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is no exception thrown here ? What is wrong in the code ?
Also I would like to know why the `&` is required to catch exception ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any integer when divided by zero is not an exception in standard C++.

The section 5.6 of C++ states:

> If the second operand of / or % is zero, the behavior is undefined.

You may also find it interesting to read this:

> Stroustrup says, in "The Design and Evolution of C++" (Addison Wesley,
>   1994), "low-level events, such as arithmetic overflows and divide by
>   zero, are assumed to be handled by a dedicated lower-level mechanism
>   rather than by exceptions. This enables C++ to match the behaviour of
>   other languages when it comes to arithmetic. It also avoids the
>   problems that occur on heavily pipelined architectures where events
>   such as divide by zero are asynchronous."`

Answer (score 3):

For the second question:
We catch exceptions by reference (&) because polymorphic types can only act "polymorphically" through a pointer or a reference. Exceptions are polymorphic types, because we can have multiple classes deriving from `std::exception` that we want to catch generically.

Since by convention we throw exceptions by value, only references can work at the catch site.

Comment: it's better to catch en exception by `const&` if you don't plan to modify it

Comment: @AndyT Of course it's better, but somehow that's not what people do for exceptions most of the time.
In fact, I'm surprised we can catch exceptions by non-const reference at all, since exceptions aren't really lvalues

Answer (score 2):

In C++, **division by zero is undefined behavior** - it doesn't throw an exception.

From a recent working draft of the C++ Standard (chapter 5, *Expressions*), regarding expressions that are not mathematically defined:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exception thrown in your code, and no exception caught.

You could throw an exception if `y == 0` and catch it in the catch block:

```
try
{
    if (y == 0) throw(string("Divide by zero not allowed"));
    int z=x/y;
    cout<<"z="<<z;
}
catch (const string &e)
{
    cout << "exception caught: "<< e;
}
```

We don't need to catch an exception by reference but it is preferred.

Since we're throwing a string, we need to catch a string too.

We could also throw a string literal and catch it:

```
try
{
    if (y == 0) throw("Divide by zero not allowed");
    int z=x/y;
    cout<<"z="<<z;
}
catch (const char* e)
{
    cout << "exception caught: "<< e;
}
```

Comment: I would advise against throwing generic objects and built in types. Although C++ does allow it the conventional behaviour is to use an exception class derived from `std::exception` such as a [`std::domain_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/domain_error).

Answer (score 1):

Division by 0 is undefined in C++, so all you can do is throw and catch an exception :-

```
int main()
{
int x=5, y=0, z=1;
try
{
    if (y==0)
    throw y;
    else
    z=x/y;
    cout<<z;
}
catch (int)
{
    cout<<"division by zero error";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this has UB. You have to throw before doing the division.